# ¿Cómo poner texto sobre una imagen en HTML?

Tags: html, css, html5

He visto que algunas páginas contienen imágenes con un texto sobre puesto, pero la etiqueta **img** no puede contener otras etiquetas ya que sólo es así:

```
<img src="algo.com/una_imagen">
```

Intenté lo siguiente:

```
<div>
<img src="algo.com/una_imagen">
<p>Texto</p>
</div>
```

Pero el texto sólo aparece debajo de la imagen.

Comment: Mirate la etiqueta canvas.

Comment: La imagen con `position:relative;` y el texto con `position:absolute;top: 150px;` es una opción.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Importante poner tu imagen en posición `relative` y tu caja de texto en `absolute` como ya te han mencionado.

Un ejemplo simple.

```css
div, img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;  
  width: 300px;
}

div p {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -16px;
  left: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://oi67.tinypic.com/28a11js.jpg">
  <p>Texto</p>
</div>
```

Si buscas un efecto `hover`, te dejare una alternativa.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height:0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://oi67.tinypic.com/28a11js.jpg" alt="" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Mi texto</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fuente: [Image Hover Overlay](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_overlay.asp)