# ¿Como poner texto sobre una imagen usando CSS?

Tags: css, css3

Necesito que mis imagenes tengan un texto arriba con la descripción de cada una de ellas! Intenté tocar las positions del CSS y me anda bien con 3 de las 4, en la cuarta imagen se me descuajeringa todo, no sé porque :(

**HTML:**

```
<div class="helados container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 l4">
            <img th:src="@{/images/chocolate.png}" />
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col s12 l4">
            <img th:src="@{/images/crema.png}" />
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col s12 l4">
            <img th:src="@{/images/dulceDeLeche.png}" />
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col s12 l4">
            <img th:src="@{/images/frutales.png}" />
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.helados {
        padding: 0 1.5rem;
    }
.helados img {
        width: 100%;
    }
  .container {
    width: 100%;
}

.helados.container {
    padding: 0;
}

.helados.container .col {
    padding: 0 0.75rem !important;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero hacer es que en cada una de las imagenes (sobre ellas) aparezca un simple texto que diga CHOCOLATE, FRUTALES, DULCE DE LECHE y CREMAS para que quede más lindo para el usuario.

Gracias totales :)

Comment: Añade el codigo css.

Comment: Perdón, ahí lo subí

Comment: Que texto quieres ubicar arriba, el elemento <a> ?

Comment: No, un texto cualquiera ... puede ser un <span>, no hice la etiqueta

Comment: mira [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/81332/c%C3%B3mo-poner-texto-sobre-una-imagen-en-html) hacen la misma pregunta y obtiene la solución.

Comment: Juega con `position: relative` para las imágenes y `position: absolute` para el texto. Si tienes alguna duda de como funcionan puedes consultar la siguiente pregunta-auto respuesta que publiqué hace un tiempo [¿Cual es la diferencia entre position: relative, position: absolute y position: fixed?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/37930/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-position-relative-position-absolute-y-position/37931#37931)

Comment: Gracias a todos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo que a mí me funcionó.

```css
div, img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;  
  width: 300px;
}

div p {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -16px;
  left: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fXCarlD.jpg">
  <p>Texto</p>
</div>
```

[Más información.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/81336/50608)

Answer (score 1):

**Saludos**
Debes crear o tener tu imagen dentro de un contenedor en este caso un div,adicional la descripcion puede ir dentro de un span, tag personal, div..etc...en este caso uso un span:

```
<div class='img'>
<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/31/Ice_Cream_dessert_02.jpg/220px-Ice_Cream_dessert_02.jpg'/>
<span>Copa de Chocolate</span>
</div>
```

Para aplicar los estilos uso este codigo css:

```
<style>
div.img{
  display:table;
}
div.img img{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
div.img span{
 line-height:normal;
 font-size:11px;
 display:table-caption;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 background:#646464;
 color:white;
 font-style:italic;
 text-align:center;
 position:relative;
 height:0;
}
div.img span span{
 background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 display:block;
 padding:3px;
 text-shadow:0 0 15px white;
}
div.centro{
  margin:0 auto;
}
div.izq{
  float:left;
}
div.der{
  float:right;
}
</style>
```

**Resultado:**

[image: Resultado]

Espero te sirva de guia...!!

Comment: nota la clase centro, izq, y der permite alinear las imagenes..em la posicion deseada

Comment: Gracias hermano, yo lo solucioné :)